# How to add a time dimension for each node in Google OR-Tools

Tags: python, optimization, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I am solving the multi-depot multiple vehicles vehicle routing problem using OR-Tools and so far I have managed to set up a model in which one vehicle leaves from each depot and between them they visit each node within their maximum time allowance and then exit via the dummy node 0. However, as this is a real-world problem, at each node the vehicle is required to stop for a set time to carry out a service, with each node having a set waiting time, such as in the table below:

| Node | Duration |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 9 |
| 38 | 8 |
| ... | ... |
| 8545 | 17 |

I am unsure how to add these to each node, although the arc lengths between nodes so far represent the travel time between each node (with the assumption that all vehicles are travelling at the same speed). So my question is how I can add these wait times into the model, while still minimizing the travel time for each vehicle and keeping them below their maximum threshold of 25200 seconds (corresponding to a 7-hour shift). I have included my working code below:

```
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

The distance matrix was fed in from a csv laid out like so:

| Blank | 4 | 38 | 71 | 90 | 94 | ... | 8545 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 0 | 1280 | 1762 | 1406 | 1589 | ... | 1017 |
| 38 | 1280 | 0 | 681 | 202 | 385 | ... | 1433 |
| 71 | 1762 | 681 | 0 | 503 | 0 | ... | 0 |
| 90 | 1406 | 202 | 503 | 0 | 0 | ... | 1559 |
| 94 | 1589 | 385 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... | 1742 |
| .. | .. | ... | ... | ... | ... | 0 | ... |
| 8545 | 1017 | 1433 | 0 | 1559 | 1742 | ... | 0 |

```
CareDist_Matrix = np.loadtxt(open("CareDistances-FULL.csv", "rb"), dtype=int, delimiter=",", skiprows=1)
CareDist_Matrix
```

And the main body of the model follows:

```
def create_data_model():
    """Stores the data for the problem."""
    data = {}
    data['distance_matrix'] = CareDist_Matrix
    data['num_vehicles'] = 6
    data['starts'] = [3, 7, 14, 104, 185, 220]
    data['ends'] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    return data

def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):
    """Prints solution on console."""
    max_route_distance = 0
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
        route_distance = 0
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            plan_output += ' {} -> '.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
            previous_index = index
            index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
            route_distance += routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(
                previous_index, index, vehicle_id)
        plan_output += '{}\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
        plan_output += 'Distance of the route: {}m\n'.format(route_distance)
        print(plan_output)
        max_route_distance = max(route_distance, max_route_distance)
    print('Maximum of the route distances: {}m'.format(max_route_distance))
```

```
    """Entry point of the program."""
    # Instantiate the data problem.
    data = create_data_model()

    # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['distance_matrix']),
                                           data['num_vehicles'], data['starts'],
                                           data['ends'])

    # Create Routing Model.
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)


    # Create and register a transit callback.
    def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the distance between the two nodes."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)

    # Define cost of each arc.
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

    # Add Distance constraint.
    dimension_name = 'Distance'
    routing.AddDimension(
        transit_callback_index,
        0,  # no slack
        25200,  # vehicle maximum travel distance
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        dimension_name)
    distance_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dimension_name)
    distance_dimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100)

    # Setting first solution heuristic.
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)

    # Solve the problem.
    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

    # Print solution on console.
    if solution:
        print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution)
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the duration to the travel in the callback function. So, total time to visit a node is the travel time to that node plus the action time in that node:

```
def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
    """Returns the distance between the two nodes."""
    # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
    from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
    to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
    return data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node] + duration['to_index']
```

Comment: I am also looking for similar solution with one added complexity, I want to add load time at depot into time_dimension and this load time is function of total demand/capacity (#Items loaded). Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: I suppose you can check in distance_callback function if from_node is a depot and in that case calculate and add load time to the result returned.

Comment: I had a similar problem as @Bhanyday Birla. I added an if-statement to the end of distance callback which worked well. (mine is time callback, but that's easy to adapt)

`if manager.IndexToNode(to_index) == data['depot']:
     return data['time_matrix'][from_node][to_node]
else:
     return data['time_matrix'][from_node][to_node] + data['service_time']`